# Set dropdown list inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Repeater control on asp.net page which is binded at runtime. There is a dropdown list inside the item template of asp.net repeater control.

I am wondering if it is possible to add list items at design time. I can bind dropdown at run time but not sure if it is possible to do at design time.

This is what i have tried so far but no luck;

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlContact" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Text="select" Value="0" Selected="True" ></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="phone" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InspectorID").ToString() + "|phone" %>' ></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="email" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InspectorID").ToString() + "|email" %>' ></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think it's possible do do something like that.  Anyway, what's the need to bind an Id as you know you have only two values? You can simply write

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlContact" runat="server">
 <asp:ListItem Text="select" Value="0" Selected="True" ></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="phone" Value="phone" ></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="email" Value="email" ></asp:ListItem>
```

and just use it.

Each one of your repeater items will have its own dropdownlist with its own selected value that you can read and use as you need.

Comment: How can i find out that which inspector has which selected value?

Comment: loop the repeater items and for each item call (item.FindControl("ddlContact") as DropDownList).SelectedValue. You need the code in an answer so it's more clear?

Comment: loop would give me a selected value but it won't tell me the inspector id.

Comment: You have sto store the id in another control inside the repeater, for example a hidden field that you can referecnce in the same way (findControl etc...)

Comment: sorry for not being very clear. Inspector id is already in the other cell of the table. First cell has inspector id and other one has dropdown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75660/discussion-between-user1263981-and-paolo-costa).

Answer (score 0):

Use the onitemdatabound method to bind item specific data for each item in your repeater: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx